# C# RestSharp library and Kerberos authentication

Tags: kerberos, restsharp

What about C# RestSharp library compatibility with Kerberos authentication?

I can see there is a `NtlmAuthenticator` but do we need to implement the same with Kerberos or is it managed automatically by underlying HTTP call?